# Fetching objects from that are inside other objects

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've been using MongoDB since a week and I'm having a lot of fun with it!

So far the test application I'm building as Projects and Milestones. See the structure below:

```
{
  "code": "test-project",
  "milestones": [
    {
      "name": "Test Milestone",
      "code": "test-milestone"
    },
    {
      "name": "Test Milestone 2",
      "code": "test-milestone-2"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Test Project"
}
```

I'm now making an edit form for the Milestones. I'd like to edit let's say, "Test Milestone 2". So, so far I've been getting the related Project, and then select the right Milestone from the associated collection. But I'd like to know if there's a way to directly get a Milestone? (in my case)

If yes then could you give me an example of how to do it please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a straight query. You just need to use the [Positional Operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator).

Let's say you want to update "Test Milestone 2" to "Test Milestone Two". You can run the following query:

```
 db.Projects.update( {"milestones.name" : "Test Milestone 2"}, {$set : {"milestones.$.name" : "Test Milestone Two"}} )
```

The `$` holds the place of your original array find (the first portion of the `update` statement). This lets you jump right to the element of the array you wish to modify.

Glad to hear you're enjoying MongoDB - it's quite fun.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But what if another project has a milestone called "Test Milestone 2" ? In the example you gave me, this is for ALL projects, so that what I'm wondering. Thanks!

Comment: The query I gave will change the name of all milestones that match "Test Milestone 2". As it operates, each Positional Operator will apply to the current document it's affecting. If you want to affect only one, you'll need to filter down the criteria in the first part of the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Embed your milestone array into the project itself.

Or keep doing what you are doing right now. (you are not doing it wrong. it's simply the nature of it)

Comment: Milestones are embedded in my Projects, no? Could you show me an example of what you're saying please? Thanks!